# Differentiate between two equally valued, differently named enum values

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, enums, reference

Short description:

I have an enum with the same value for 2 different enum constants:

```
namespace MOTOR
{
     using AXES = enum : int
     {
         X,
         Y,
         SPECIAL = 0X01,
     };
}
```

so that SPECIAL has the same value as Y (both are 0x01).

I also have a function that does the following:

```
ErrType CMotorBase::ConvertAxis(MOTOR::AXES& Axis)
{
     switch(Axis)
     {
          case MOTOR::AXES::X: Axis = MOTOR::AXES::SPECIAL;
          break;
     }
     return NO_ERROR;
}
```

when I try to use the function like this:

```
MOTOR::AXES Axis = MOTOR::AXES::X;
ErrType Err = ConvertAxis(Axis);
...
other code
...
```

I expect that when I hit breakpoint on "other code", the value of Axis will be
MOTOR::AXES::SPECIAL on visual studio debugger.

but I get that Axis = MOTOR::AXES::Y; (same value, different constant name)

they both have the same value of course so the "logic" is ok, but another programmer will think something went wrong while debugging.

Any idea how to solve it? I want that both value and name will be correct when returning from the function.

Comment: Give them different values.  Y and SPECIAL are the same so how is it supposed tell the difference?

Comment: The visual studio debugger just shows you the value you put in (`1`) and discovers a fancy name for it, if available. How the hell may it guess you meant another name?

Comment: If I use a debugger inside the function after the assignment, the debugger knows its MOTOR::AXES::SPECIAL and not MOTOR::AXES::Y.

I want to use the same value for a purpose.

Comment: Explain why they need to be the same and what your goal is. Maybe there is a completely different solution to your problem that will work good for you.

Answer (score 2):

Both `MOTOR::AXES::Y` and `MOTOR::AXES::SPECIAL` have the same value, so the compiler (or anybody, for that matter) cannot distinguish them everywhere.

You might want to give `MOTOR::AXES::SPECIAL` a different value, but give it the same treatment as `MOTOR::AXES::Y` where applicable. This might add some complexity to your program, but that is the cost for the extra "intelligence" you want.

Edit:
Alternatively (based on your comment), you might want to separate your "normal" (internal) and "special" (external) enums into two separate enums, so they can be distinguished by type. Something like this:

```
enum AXIS {
    X.
    Y
};
enum SPECIAL_AXIS {
    SPECIAL_X = AXIS::Y,
    SPECIAL_Y = /* a value */
};
```

Comment: Peter, Thanks for your answer.

I need to use the same value for them both for a reason:

I didn't write the entire code but the goal is to distinguish between Axes enumeration as an internal enumeration by the application and external  enumeration determined by the motor protocol.

so in my case(for real)
X = 0
Y = 1
...

X_EXTERNAL = 1

and when I try to convert X to X_EXTERNAL I get Y instead.

understand?

Comment: In that case, you still give them all different values and then translate the values.  As in: `int GetActualValue( MOTOR::AXES axis )`.